# snort+snorby snapshot image or auto-installer

Tags: image

Is there a snapshot image file (*.img) like 'Raspbian' or 'Pidora' available for the RPi that comes with already installed passive IDS: snorby+snort+pulledpork+barnyard2+apache2+MySQL?

Or is there something like 'Autosnort' for an raspberry os available? Is it possible to port this script thats originally using Debian 6.x and 7.x for Raspbian?

http://github.com/da667/Autosnort

Answer (score 2):

If it supports Wheezy it should work fine on Rasbian, as Rasbian is based on Wheezy. Looking through the script briefly I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: That's a Ruby error you're getting. It seems like the dm-rails gem isn't either installed or is installed improperly. I'm not a ruby expert, but try adding `dm-rails` to the list of gems installed in snorby-debian.sh on line 101 (https://github.com/da667/Autosnort/blob/master/Autosnort%20-%20Debian/snorby-debian.sh#L101).